# Hot Module Replacement of a particular module only works once while the App component can be HMR-ed all the time

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, hot-module-replacement

In my project I am using Webpacks HMR feature to dynamically import and render the React App component on new changes which works all the time. However I have another file where I store a Redux reducer with a corresponding `module.hot.accept` call that only gets called once, ever. I stripped almost all dependencies and even removed Redux and tracked this down to Webpack itself.

My `App.Store.ts` basically looks like this:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:missing-jsdoc
import { AppReducer } from "App.Reducer";
import { createStore, Store } from "redux";

function configureStore(): Store {
    const store: Store = createStore(AppReducer);

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept(
            "App.Reducer",
            (): void => {
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
                console.log("This is only called once and not a second time :(");
            }
        );
    }

    return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

When I change something in my `App.Reducer.ts` (no matter what), the handler is only called once, ever. On subsequent changes of the file the debug output with `console.log` is not visible at all.

This is either a more complicated Webpack HMR issue or my handling of HMR with `module.hot.accept` being wrong. Please refer to my linked MWE for more details.

### MWE

A complete MWE can be found here: https://gitlab.com/NearAutomata/webpack-hmr-issue. Clone and run the following commands:

```
yarn
yarn run build-main
yarn run build-renderer-hot
```

And in a second terminal run

```
yarn run start-hot
```